# My question is on force, displacement and energy relationship

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

We know force times displacement is the work done.Consider an object with mass 'm' and initial velocity 'v'.Let the object experience a constant force 'F' for a time 't' also let the force,the initial velocity 'v',the displacement of the object all be in the same direction.Then the displacement of the object will be vt+(F×t^2)/2m.Then will the workdone be equal to F{vt+[(1/2)(F/m)(t^2)]}?If it is ,then my question is how the initial velocity contributed to the work done by the force 'F' on the object?

Answer (score 1):

Well, force times distance is not work. The correct expression for work is $\displaystyle W=\int \vec{F}.\vec{dS}$, where S is the displacement (not distance). Now, for cases where $\vec{F}$ is constant, we get $W=\vec{F}.\vec{S}$.
Secondly, the formula that you used to calculate the distance, is actually the formula for displacement! $(S=ut+at²/2)$.
Now, you have the magnitude of force and the magnitude of displacement, buy you can't just multiply them together, because the expression says that work done is the dot product of the two vectors. So, we know that $\vec{F}.\vec{S}=|F||S|\cos \theta$ where theta is the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{S}$.
Now, your expression will be correct only of $\cos \theta=1$ implies $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{S}$ are in the same direction.

Comment: Well, then the equation with those conditions is true! I was just wondering how the displacement made by the object for it's initial velocity also have contributed to the work done by the force 'F'. I am talking about the term 'F×v×t' in the above work done equation I mentioned.